# Is there a function to count all positive numbers in a vector?

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I'm in a search of a function that can count all positive numbers in a `vector`! And I need your help. The only function that I've found so far is `std::count()` from `algorithm`, but it only searches the container for elements equivalent to a certain value. Maybe there is a way to make this function search for matches in a certain range (this range will be from 1 to +infinity in my case)? Thanks.

Comment: You are very close to your solution: there is `std::count_if`

Comment: `std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind2nd(std::greater<int>(), 0))`

Comment: @milleniumbug, thanks a lot! I think I skipped it somehow...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest would be `std::count_if`.

You can use it like that:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int count_bigger(const std::vector<int>& elems) {
    return std::count_if(elems.begin(), elems.end(), [](int c){return c > 0;});
}
```